# Node.js, Cygwin and Socket.io walk into a bar... Node.js throws ENOBUFS and everyone dies

Tags: javascript, dns, cygwin, node.js

I'm hoping someone here can help me out, I'm not having much luck figuring this out myself. I'm running node.js version 0.3.1 on Cygwin. I'm using Connect and Socket.io. I seem to be having some random problems with DNS or something, I haven't quite figured it out. The end result is that I the server is running fine, but when a browser attempts to connect to it the initial HTTP Request works, Socket.io connects, and then the server dies (output below).

I don't think it has anything to do with the HTTP request because the server gets a lot data posted to it, and it was receiving requests and responding up until my connection that killed it. I've googled around and the closest thing I've found is DNS being set improperly. It's a network program meant to run only on an internal network, so I've set the `nameserver x.x.x.x` in my `/etc/resolv.conf` to the internal DNS. I've also added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in addition. I'm not sure what else to check, but would be grateful of any help.

## In `node.exe.stackdump`

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=610C51B9
eax=00000000 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000000 edx=00000308 esi=00000000 edi=010FCCB0
ebp=010FCAEC esp=010FCAC4 program=\\?\E:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\node.exe, pid 3296, thread unknown (0xBEC)
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
010FCAEC  610C51B9  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
010FCBFC  610C5B55  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
010FCCBC  610C693A  (FFFFFFFF, FFFFFFFF, 750334F3, FFFFFFFE)
010FCD0C  61027CB2  (00000002, F4B994D5, 010FCE64, 00000002)
010FCD98  76306B59  (00000002, 010FCDD4, 763069A4, 00000002)
End of stack trace
```

## Node Output:

```
    node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: ENOBUFS, No buffer space available
    at doConnect (net.js:642:19)
    at net.js:803:9
    at dns.js:166:30
    at IOWatcher.callback (dns.js:48:15)
```

## EDIT

I'm hitting an LDAP server using `http.createClient` immediately after a client connects to get information, and that seems to be where the problem is that is causing ENOBUFS. I've edited the source [to include `&& errno != ENOBUFS`](https://github.com/ry/node/blob/v0.3.1/src/node_net.cc#L368) which now prevents the server from dying, however now the LDAP request isn't working. I'm not sure what the problem is that would cause that though. As I mentioned this is an internal only application, so I set the DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` to the DNS servers that are being applied to the host machine. Not sure if this is part of the issue?

## EDIT 2

Here's some output from `gdb --args ./node_g --debug ../myscript.js`. I'm not sure if this is related to ENOBUFS, however, as it seems to be disconnecting immediately after connection with Socket.io

```
    [New thread 672.0x100]
Error: dll starting at 0x76e30000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76250000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76e30000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76f50000 not found.
[New thread 672.0xc90]
[New thread 672.0x448]
debugger listening on port 5858
[New thread 672.0xbf4]
14 Jan 18:48:57 - socket.io ready - accepting connections
[New thread 672.0xed4]
[New thread 672.0xd68]
[New thread 672.0x1244]
[New thread 672.0xf14]
14 Jan 18:49:02 - Initializing client with transport "websocket"
assertion "b[1] == 0" failed: file "../src/node.cc", line 933, function: ssize_t
 node::DecodeWrite(char*, size_t, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, node::encoding)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x7724f861 in ntdll!RtlUpdateClonedSRWLock ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x7724f861 in ntdll!RtlUpdateClonedSRWLock ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
#1  0x7724f861 in ntdll!RtlUpdateClonedSRWLock ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
#2  0x75030816 in WaitForSingleObjectEx ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KernelBase.dll
#3  0x0000035c in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: If you don't post the code itself, well, it might be a little hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Code isn't the problem. I'm updating the question with more info.

Comment: The stack trace isn't too useful without symbol names. Maybe run node under gdb and get a meaningful stack trace?

Comment: have you tried running it using node v0.2.6?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this problem. However, I'm positive Chuck Norris would've already solved it with some violence - have you tried that? +1 for the title :D

Comment: What exactly is the question, and how is it programming related?

Comment: @generalhenry: No I hadn't, but I did that before I left today and I left it running, we'll see how that fares in the morning. @Pumbaa80: ENOBUFS is causing me to be unable to make outbound requests in Node.js on Cygwin. I'm not sure if it's a problem w/ the Node.js source, or Cygwin.

Comment: @generalhenry no go, same problem with v0.2.6

Comment: @ohmantics: I'm attempting to run Node.js with gdb, but it's not finding my modules and therefore not loading them. I don't think it will be useful if it's not running in the same condition. I'm trying `gdb --args ./node_g --debug ../myscript.js`, ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I digged around a bit, and after your second edit I found [this bug](https://github.com/ry/node/issues/issue/384) on the issue list.

I doesn't state whether this was encountered under cygwin or not, but the error that it is hitting leads down to this piece of code:

```
  uint16_t * twobytebuf = new uint16_t[buflen];

  str->Write(twobytebuf, 0, buflen, String::HINT_MANY_WRITES_EXPECTED);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < buflen; i++) {
    unsigned char *b = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&twobytebuf[i]);
    assert(b[1] == 0); // this assertion fails
    buf[i] = b[0];
  }
```

From what I can read (with my rusted C) it will convert it will create a new uin16 array and write the contents of the V8 string in their, then it will ensure that casting did not write any values outside the range of `0 - 255`, and that's exactly what fails here.

I couldn't find anything regarding whether this is a V8 issue or not.

Since the code was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ry/node/commit/8890070b88361c1fa7cc0d6f9ed9410a7dd0509a#diff-1), the only thing I can suggest here is to try pulling the tree from a **commit before the code was added**. Since all versions after that have the crashing code.

If that works, I would recommend you to file another bug report on the issue Node.js issue list, although I made do this later this day.

Comment: That commit was a year and a half ago, I don't know if the modules/my code would even work in that environment though? Is it possible to just change the code in a newer version.

Comment: I guess that would be possible, but it would need quite some testing and my knowledge of C++ V8 and C++ is very limited, it would be best to post this on the Node.js google group or maybe even go into #node.js on freenode, since the issue tracker on GitHub gets ignored most of the time.

Comment: Bloody hell! A hardcoded little-endian assumption! That code needs to be taken out back and shot!

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: I sent it to the google group as well, and tried my luck in the IRC channel, but so far no luck...

Comment: I think this is definitely a problem, but I don't think it's my problem. Whenever I added && errno != ENOBUFS to node_net.cc the program stopped crashing, it just prevented outgoing connections. When gdb runs it seems to crash right when socket.io connects, which is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to answer this one but +1 for the subject line.

Node.js comes with a test suite along with the main build, have you run that? I had built node successfully but because I'd omitted OpenSSL my web socket tests were failing. Install/rebuild fixed it. The test projects helped me diagnose the issue.

suggest doing "make test" as http://nodejs.org/#download describes.